# XenForo Login Authentication

Tags: php, xenforo

I'm working on a 3rd party application, and I need to make a stand alone login authentication. I don't want to setup a session or create any local data vars of the sort, I just want to check the username/password for a match. The issue standing is that the XF authentication system doesn't make much sense to me. I've looked around the official XF website, but I haven't gathered much. I understand that password/salt data is stored in the `xf_user_authentication` table, but I don't know what to make of it. Would anyone be so kind as to explain to me how passwords are formed and what does what within this table?

Comment: Look at \XenForo_Model_User::validateAuthentication() function. I think it will explain something

Comment: I solved my issue some time ago, turns out the encoding/hash data is serialized in the `data` field.

Comment: Great. It would be good to have your solution posted as an answer in this question.

Comment: @user1117742456, it would be great if you can explain the solution that worked for you, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer for anyone who comes across this in the future.

XenForo stores the users passwords in `xf_user_authenticate`, but without usernames, only `user_id` to determine the user. The usernames are stored in `xf_user`. In order to compare the username & password, you'll need to `SELECT user_id FROM xf_user WHERE username LIKE ...` and using that you'll need to `SELECT data FROM xf_user_authenticate WHERE user_id LIKE ...`, then simply use `password_verify();` to compare the sanitized user input to the hashed password stored in the database. Do note that the hashed passwords are store in a .bin blob along with the cost and salt values used to hash them, these are default values of `password_verify();`, so all you'll really need to do prior to comparison is to strip the rest of the characters away from the hashed password itself using `$password = substr($password, 22, -3);` (`$password` being the string from the database) as the hashed password starts after 22 characters in with 3 trailing characters at the end, the hash being 60 characters long with the total blob character count being 85.

I as well was tasked recently with developing a login verification system that would work with the user accounts that were created on the register page on the forum. This way you can attach those scripts with the correct database connection info to any external website, even on a different server (assuming you're not using shared hosting) and successfully verify a users login request against the forum account information. From there you'll have no problems pulling things like profile information or the accounts avatars, or even their post history!

Here's what I've come up with:

First up, the obvious. Setup your database connection:

```
<?
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'phpMyAdmin Login Here');
    define('DB_PASS', 'phpMyAdmin Password Here');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'Typically [user_xenpubdatabase]');

    $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
        if (!$conn) {
            die('Database connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

Now I've also opted to use functions and store those separate from the login form, so when a user submits, the functions.php is included on login.

Here's my functions:

```
<?php
function sanitize($input, $conn){
    $input = trim($input); // removing spaces
    $strlenght = strlen($input);//get the length of the input
    for($i = 0; $i <= $strlenght; $i++) {//foreach sting char
        $input = stripslashes($input); // remove backslashes
    }
    $input = htmlspecialchars($input); // make sure code gets declared
    $input = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $input); //disable code execution
    return $input;
}

function checkForExistingAccount($username, $conn){
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT id from users where username = ?")) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $username);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

        if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){//if an account returned then rip the username already exists...
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            return true;//so return true
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    return false;

}

function checkUsername($username, $conn){

    if ($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT user_id FROM xf_user WHERE username = ?")){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "s", $username);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);

        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt2);
        if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt2) > 0){
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function getPassword($username, $conn){
    if ($stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT data FROM xf_user_authenticate WHERE username = ?")){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "s", $username);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2);

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);
        $password = substr($password, 22, -3);
        return $password;
    }

}

function checkPassword($user_pass, $hashed_pass){
    if (password_verify($user_pass, $hashed_pass)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

From there, my login script looks as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    include 'dbs.php';
    include 'functions.php';
    if (!empty($username = sanitize($_POST['username'], $conn)) && !empty($password = sanitize($_POST['password'], $conn))) {
        if (checkUsername($username, $conn)) {
            if (!empty($dbs_password = getPassword($username, $conn))) {
                if (checkPassword($password, $dbs_password)) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['active'] = 1;//never use true, some browsers are buggy with that.
                    mysqli_close($conn);//close conn then redirect
                    header('location: ../index.php');
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="danger">Sorry, you have entered wrong information</div>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo '<div class="danger">Sorry, no user found with the username: ' . $username . '</div>';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo '<div class="danger">You have to fill in all fields*</div>';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```